# vue + nuxt: dynamic import of route pages fails at render

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to speed up the loading of our vue/nuxt application. 
I follow the nice idea of splitting routing page into asynchronous loading as in 
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html

This means mainly turning

```
import Contact from '@/components/pages/Contact'
...
Router({
    routes: [
        {
            path: __('route_contact'),
            name: 'contact',
            component: Contact
        },
```

into

```
const Contact = () => import('@/components/pages/Contact');
...
Router({
    routes: [
        {
            path: __('route_contact'),
            name: 'contact',
            component: Contact
        },
```

But it unfortunately fails.

The preparation process via `nuxt build` and `nuxt start` proceeds normally, the small chunks are generated and packaged and server starts.

However when I try to render this page via front side (using internal link) there's no output, and when I do reload of the page in question (triggering SSR) I get server error with the following output of `nuxt start`:

```
{ Error: render function or template not defined in component: anonymous
at normalizeRender (/var/www/site/front/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7396:13)
at renderComponentInner (/var/www/site/front/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7520:3)
at renderComponent (/var/www/site/front/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7491:5)
at renderNode (/var/www/site/front/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7407:5)
at renderComponentInner (/var/www/site/front/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7527:3)
at renderComponent (/var/www/site/front/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7491:5)
at renderNode (/var/www/site/front/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7407:5)
at renderComponentInner (/var/www/site/front/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7527:3)
at renderComponent (/var/www/site/front/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7491:5)
at RenderContext.renderNode (/var/www/site/front/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7407:5)
at RenderContext.next (/var/www/site/front/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:2428:14)
at RenderContext.next (/var/www/site/front/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:2441:12)
at RenderContext.cachedWrite [as write] (/var/www/site/front/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:2287:9)
at RenderContext.next (/var/www/site/front/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:2432:16)
at RenderContext.cachedWrite [as write] (/var/www/site/front/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:2287:9)
at RenderContext.renderNode (/var/www/site/front/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7415:15) statusCode: 500, name: 'NuxtServerError' }
```

Does anybody have any idea what to do?

Answer (score 7):

I know it's a bit outdated post, but if anyone still stumbles upon this as I did looking up the same problem, I solved it by using the same mechanism as nuxt.js default generated router does, wrapping the component dynamic import as follows:

```
function interopDefault(promise) {
  return promise.then(m => m.default || m);
}

const HomeIndex = () => interopDefault(import('@/pages/home/index.vue'));
const HomeAboutUs = () => interopDefault(import('@/pages/home/about-us.vue'));
```

Comment: I ended up naming the function "dynamically", so it now reads nicely as `dynamically(import('...'))`

Comment: This is required to get the package `@nuxtjs/router` working with dynamic imports.